# About Hide the keyboard

Tags: ios7, keyboard

My question is :
   When I write a user login UI, because the keyboard  hide the password textfield, so I write some code to scroll up the login UI, but when the keyboard is hidden and the UI is scrolled to the old position, I find I touch the textfield which I can't get any response.

registe notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillshow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillhide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];

_username.delegate = self;
_password.delegate = self;
```

will show keyboard code:

```
- (void) keyboardWillshow:(NSNotification *)noti
 {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [noti userInfo];
    NSValue *keyValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardRect = [keyValue CGRectValue];
    int height = keyboardRect.size.height;
    userInfo = nil;
    keyValue = nil;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
    self.containView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -height+20, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2-20);
    }];
}
```

will hide keyboard code:

```
- (void)keyboardWillhide:(NSNotification *)noti
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        self.containView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2-20);
    }];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [_password resignFirstResponder];
    [_username resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Could some one help me? I use the storyboard to write the code.

Comment: Please give some more context, what language are you using and what platform?  I assume its a phone or tablet, but android, ios, something else?  Appropriate tags would help.

Comment: I'm sorry, in the code I define the HEIGHT as [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, and the WIDTH is [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, I should not use HEIGHT/2 and WIDTH/2.